# Is there a general term for disorders that involve difficulty in learning & interpreting Arithmetic Calculations?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

For example the word  [Dyslexia](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=dyslexia%20meaning&oq=dyslexia%20&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.3707j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is as a general term for disorders that involve difficulty in learning to read or interpret words, letters, and other symbols.

Similarly is there a general term for disorders that involve inability to understand & interpret arithmetic calculations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term you want is **dyscalculia**

> Severe difficulty in making arithmetical calculations, as a result of brain disorder. (Oxford Dictionary Online)

A fuller definition from the [British Dyslexia Association](http://www.bdadyslexia.org.uk/dyslexic/dyscalculia) runs

> Developmental Dyscalculia (DD) is a specific learning disorder that is characterised by impairments in learning basic arithmetic facts, processing numerical magnitude and performing accurate and fluent calculations.

Comment: +1. But *calculations* does not mean the same thing as *mathematics*. (But *calculations* might be what the OP really meant.)

Comment: I think that definition from ODO is probably a little narrow and that the term really covers more. Hard to find a succinct definition.

Comment: I added a definition from the British Dyslexia Association.

Comment: Bit long,  mathematically_challenged?